# SSRS How to get Group By Variable value from earlier set

Tags: sql, reporting-services

[image]

I have done Column Level Group By on FY Column

Here i would like to get Fy 16 Prior Year Remaining amount from this formula (FY 15 Prior Amount + FY 15 Capital - FY 15 Expenditure). If I calculate as group variable its applicable only to that FY as I cant get from previous year FY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to use custom code in your report to achieve the tablix you want.

If you are using SSDT in `Report` menu go to `Report Properties`:

[image]

Go to Code tab and paste the following code:

```
Dim previous As Integer = 100
Dim current As Integer = 0

Public Function GetPrior(ByVal Capital as Integer, ByVal Expenditure as Integer) as Integer
    current = previous
    previous = previous + Capital - Expenditure
    Return current
End Function
```

> Note the first line of the code, the previous variable was set to **100**
>   as your example but you can put any value corresponding to the **first**
>   year Prior value.

[image]

Go to the tablix you added and set it as below:

[image]

In the prior textbox put this expression:

```
=Code.GetPrior(Fields!Capital.Value,Fields!Expenditure.Value)
```

This is the preview

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: @sundaravadivel, Nice! you can select my answer as correct, click the correct symbol at right side of the answer.

Comment: Thanks its working, But here i am using another 2 column called begining capital which is addition of **Prior year WIP +Capital**, and revised capital **Prior year WIP +Capital- Expenditure**, so one column is referring another column & its causing circular reference in the formula. any help ?

Comment: Ask another question explaining in detail your specific issue in order to other users can help you too, since it doesn't have to do with the answered question here.

Comment: Hi @alejandro , i posted new question. advanced thanks for your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445290/ssrs-cycling-reference